# Sort Linq result in alphabetical order

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have List of name I need to sort in alphabetical order, but its not sorting as expected, its only bringing out similar alphabets together.

This is my code

```
[Route("api/getdeptemployee/{Id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetDepartmentEmp(int Id)
    {
        var item = (from o in db.Employee
                    join a in db.Department on o.DepartmentId equals a.Id
                    where a.Id == Id
                    select new
                    {
                        Id = o.Id,
                        LastName = o.LastName,
                        AddedBy = o.LastName + " " + o.FirstName
                    }).OrderBy(s => s.LastName).ToList();
        return Json(item);
    }
```

here is the result

```
{
    "id": 2277,
    "lastName": " IBIRONKE",
    "addedBy": " IBIRONKE ABIMBOLA "
},
{
    "id": 2278,
    "lastName": " IGBINOBA",
    "addedBy": " IGBINOBA PATRICIA"
},
{
    "id": 2279,
    "lastName": " IRUBOR",
    "addedBy": " IRUBOR CATHERINE "
},
{
    "id": 2276,
    "lastName": " KOLAWOLE",
    "addedBy": " KOLAWOLE SEGUN"
},
{
    "id": 2281,
    "lastName": " LAMPTEY",
    "addedBy": " LAMPTEY JOSEPH"
},
{
    "id": 2282,
    "lastName": " OJEDIRAN",
    "addedBy": " OJEDIRAN OLUWASEYI "
},
{
    "id": 2283,
    "lastName": "ADEBANJO",
    "addedBy": "ADEBANJO ABAYOMI "
},
{
    "id": 2296,
    "lastName": "ADENIYI",
    "addedBy": "ADENIYI ONI"
},
{
    "id": 2284,
    "lastName": "ADEPOJU",
    "addedBy": "ADEPOJU ABAYOMI "
},
{
    "id": 2297,
    "lastName": "AFOLABI-ONI",
    "addedBy": "AFOLABI-ONI OLUFUNKE "
},
{
    "id": 2285,
    "lastName": "AGBOM",
    "addedBy": "AGBOM MAURICE"
},
{
    "id": 2293,
    "lastName": "AKPU-AGBAKA",
    "addedBy": "AKPU-AGBAKA BYRON"
},
{
    "id": 2286,
    "lastName": "ASUQUO",
    "addedBy": "ASUQUO NAOMI "
},
{
    "id": 2299,
    "lastName": "AYI-SAMUEL",
    "addedBy": "AYI-SAMUEL BLESSING"
},
{
    "id": 2298,
    "lastName": "ECHEBIRI",
    "addedBy": "ECHEBIRI JUSTINE"
},
{
    "id": 2287,
    "lastName": "EDET ",
    "addedBy": "EDET  NSIKAK "
},
{
    "id": 2292,
    "lastName": "EZE",
    "addedBy": "EZE FAVOUR "
},
{
    "id": 2289,
    "lastName": "JABE",
    "addedBy": "JABE AJOM"
},
{
    "id": 2288,
    "lastName": "MADUNECHE",
    "addedBy": "MADUNECHE CHIDI "
},
{
    "id": 2280,
    "lastName": "MUSTAPHA",
    "addedBy": "MUSTAPHA TRACY "
},
{
    "id": 2274,
    "lastName": "OLAWOYIN",
    "addedBy": "OLAWOYIN KELECHI "
},
{
    "id": 2290,
    "lastName": "ONAA",
    "addedBy": "ONAA JAMES "
},
{
    "id": 2275,
    "lastName": "SORINWA",
    "addedBy": "SORINWA OLUFUNKE "
},
{
    "id": 2295,
    "lastName": "UGBE",
    "addedBy": "UGBE JOHN-PAUL"
},
{
    "id": 2294,
    "lastName": "UWAH",
    "addedBy": "UWAH FRANCIS"
},
{
    "id": 2291,
    "lastName": "ZOCLI",
    "addedBy": "ZOCLI ANDREW"
}
```

its not sorted in alphabetical order, please how do I solve this. Is there a way I can make it start from A-Z, just in alphabetical order?. Thanks

Comment: Try cut spaces from lastName like `OrderBy(s => s.LastName.Trim())`

Comment: It is sorted by last name properly. Look, you have a space character in the first few. Space is before A

Comment: @AleksAndreev thanks alot, using the Trim worked, put your comment as answer, let me mark it as answered

Comment: You may also wish to clean the data in your database - since the bug is in the **writing** not the reading.

Comment: @Franck thanks, the space was really the problem

Comment: @EmmanuelIkechukwu the actual solution is to clean the data. Trimming means the server won't be able to use indexes during sorting resulting in far worse performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed by **Aleks Andreev** in the comment

Try cut spaces from lastName like `OrderBy(s => s.LastName.Trim())`

Answer (score 0):

I see that some of the strings in your data have a space at the beginning. You might want to trim the strings before sorting and returning them.

Additionally, sorting in LINQ to Objects is case-sensitive, which may also be affected by the data in your database. Since you are still using LINQ to SQL (as per Panagiotis's comment), you may skip the `ToLower()` call and rely on database support.

Here is how you can fix your code so that data are trimmed, and sorted in case-insensitive manner (mind the calls to Trim and ToLower):

```
[Route("api/getdeptemployee/{Id}")]
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult GetDepartmentEmp(int Id)
{
    var item = (from o in db.Employee
                join a in db.Department on o.DepartmentId equals a.Id
                where a.Id == Id
                select new
                {
                    Id = o.Id,
                    LastName = o.LastName.Trim(),
                    AddedBy = o.LastName.Trim() + " " + o.FirstName.Trim()
                }).OrderBy(s => s.LastName.ToLower()).ToList();
    return Json(item);
}
```

Comment: Sorting in SQL is typically *not* case sensitive. Whether it is or not is controlled by the field's collation. In most cases, case-*in*sensitive collations are used

Comment: You are right, that can be omitted in this query, so I've edited the answer. Thank you for pointing out.